# How send a notification once DataFactory Job runs or failed?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I wanted to send a notification once DataFactory Job runs or failed.

I don't want to send it through Logic apps and Azure alters.

Please suggest some way to manage this situation. 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know,ADF has own **Alert/Monitor** mechanism.Please see the button in the ADF portal as below.

[image]

You could create new Alert Rule.

[image]

Configure alert Criteria.

[image]

Configure alert channel.

[image]

Comment: This Will send lots of emails I want some custom notification or some solution so that I can store log information to my DB

Comment: @GauravGangwar Ok, then you need to do this programmatically,please create the custom notification with monitor code:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-programmatically

Comment: @GauravGangwar You could create a time trigger azure function to check the status of your adf pipeline, and send the notification as soon as the exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combination of Azure Function + SendGrid.

SendGrid is a cloud-based email service, and on a free pricing tier, you can send 25k emails. Support .NET,Java and Python (i think).

So write an azure function that will send an email via SendGrid. 
On pipeline failure, you will just call AF.

I would suggest you in this scenario to pay as you go for AF, and as I said free tier for SendGrid. Minimum cost.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email here you can find how to use SendGrid (code example)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-functions-now-supported-as-a-step-in-azure-data-factory-pipelines/

Answer (score 0):

I use webhook to send messages to Team. Here is the official template.

[image]

### failed

here is my UI. I add a Lookup Activity to search a non-existent DB table to raise an error.

[image]

And then I connect it to copy activity.

[image]

### succeeded

It's the same way, but not need to raise an error.

[image]